# Does a docker container have its own TCP/IP stack?

Tags: networking, docker, tcp, linux-containers

I'm trying to understand what's happening under the hood to a network packet coming from the wire connected to the host machine and directed to an application inside a Docker container.

If it were a classic VM, I know that a packet arriving on the host would be transmitted by the hypervisor (say VMware, VBox etc.) to the virtual NIC of the VM and from there through the TCP/IP stack of the guest OS, finally reaching the application.

In the case of Docker, I know that a packet coming on the host machine is forwarded from the network interface of the host to the `docker0` bridge, that is connected to a `veth` pair ending on the virtual interface `eth0` inside the container. But after that? Since all Docker containers use the host kernel, is it correct to presume that the packet is processed by the TCP/IP stack of the host kernel? If so, how?

I would really like to read a **detailed** explanation (or if you know a resource feel free to link it) about what's really happening under the hood. I already carefully read [this](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/docs/sources/articles/networking.md) page, but it doesn't say everything.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Yes, the host TCP/IP stack is used. After reading the page you linked to, it's hard to add much more except reading the linux kernel and docker source code- do you have any specific questions rather ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
Well, for example it is unclear to me how the data is transmitted form the `docker0` bridge to the `eth0` of the host machine: I tried to use wireshark but I can only see packets exchanged from `docker0` and the `vethXYZ`; I also presume that between `docker0` and `eth0` there is a NAT since addresses change but I didn't found documentation about it.

Comment: Right, most of that, including the NAT rules employed by docker is explained in that document.

Comment: My fault, I skipped the paragraph "Binding container ports to the host" because of the title; sorry for wasting your time. I would suggest you to convert your first comment in an answer, since you answered about the TCP/IP stack, I would accept it gladly :-)

Answer (score 13):

The network stack, as in "the code", is definitely not in the container, it's in the kernel of which there's only one shared by the host and all containers (you already knew this). What each container has is its own separate network *namespace*, which means it has its own network interfaces and routing tables.

Here's a brief article introducing the notion with some examples: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/
and I found this article helpful too:
http://containerops.org/2013/11/19/lxc-networking/

I hope this gives you enough pointers to dig deeper.