# How to capture packets for single docker container

Tags: networking, docker

There have many container running on the host. And I want to capture packets for the one container of these. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Wireshark is what you need

Comment: Filter the network by the mac address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611001/does-a-docker-container-have-its-own-tcp-ip-stack 
and https://github.com/manell/wireshark 
Check above two links might be helpfull.

Comment: I am trying to find this too.

This is what needs to be done but I am struggling to get the right commands.

1. Find the interface which docker creates in host. Remember that one would be internal interface in the docker container and one would be interface in the host.
2. We can simply do tcpdump on that interface using 
    $tcpdump -i <interface>

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can bind to the network namespace of one container to another:

```
docker run -it --rm --net container:<container_name> \
  nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump ...
```

To see more about the netshoot image used above, see: https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot

Answer (score 38):

From and for a workstation with Wireshark:

```sh
docker exec -ti <container id> cat /sys/class/net/eth0/iflink

28
```

```sh
ip link | grep 28

28: veth11b0a6c@if27: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default
```

[image: Wireshark interfaces]

Comment: This is a neat outside the box solution. Won't always work but in the situations it would it'd be beneficial.

Answer (score 23):

- First, get `pid` of the container you are interested in

  ```
  docker inspect --format "{{ .State.Pid }}" "$CONTAINER_ID"
  ```
- Then enter the same [network namespace](https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/)

  ```
  nsenter -n -t "$PID"
  ```
- Finally, run `tcpdump`

Answer (score 1):

In rare cases (or maybe when you create your own container images) the container may have tcpdump installed.  In that case, you can issue the following command to get a 10 second capture saved to the host computer (outside of the container):

```
# Set CONATINER_ID to the process you want to perform a dump from
# Consider docker ps for finding the container id
# for example, CONTAINER_ID=$( docker ps | grep $IMAGE | awk '{print $1}' )
docker exec $CONTAINER_ID bash -c 'timeout 10 tcpdump -i eth0 -w /dev/stdout' > capture.pcap
```

Answer (score 0):

One-Click solution that doesn't require any CLI dances:

1. deploy discovery and capture service: [Edgeshark](https://github.com/siemens/edgeshark)
2. install plugin for Wireshark to use the capture service: [cshargextcap](https://github.com/siemens/cshargextcap)